# How to deactivate all children in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I only deactivate all children in unity and leaving the parent active?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
//Assuming parent is the parent game object
for (int i = 0; i < parent.transform.childCount; i++)
{
    var child = parent.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
    if (child != null)
        child.SetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: Tyvm this is what i am looking for =)

Answer (score 17):

```
foreach (Transform child in transform)
    child.gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

Comment: shorter than the checked answer!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
public void DisableChildren()  
{    
    foreach (Transform child in transform)     
    {  
        child.gameObject.SetActiveRecursively(false);   
    }   
}
```

JS version (if needed):

```
function DisableChildren()   
{   
    for (var child : Transform in transform)    
    {   
        child.gameObject.SetActiveRecursively(false);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: SetActiveRecursively is obsolete in Unity 4.